# calculating outward normal of a non-convex polyhedral

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry, polyhedra

If all nodes of a polyhedron (may be non-convex) and their coordinates are known, the points of a face are given in order (anti-clockwise or clockwise around the outward normal), how do I obtain the outward normal vector of each face?

Here is a method for convex polyhedron:
[Computing face normals and winding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454789/computing-face-normals-and-winding)

How about a general polyhedron that could be non-convex?

Comment: Without any research I'd guess the hard part is to calculate what vectors form a single face and not calculating the normal vector of a single face!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the normals of a box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603469/how-to-calculate-the-normals-of-a-box)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Good find, but counting ray intersections (as suggested there) is quite a tricky computation, in my experience.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke true, but only if you intend to use an acceleration structure. A naive "loop through and check each" approach would be more or less trivial (since there are many code samples of Moller-Trumbore on the interwebs)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: One must be careful when the ray passes through a vertex, is collinear with an edge, coplanar with a face. Etc. Of course it can be done correctly. And there is existing code, you are right.

Comment: If you have a manifold data structure where the faces can be extracted as a consistently anti-clockwise or clockwise sequence of edges, then this is a very well-studied problem. The classical solution is Newell's algorithm: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method. Fix the orientation of one face F0 of your polyhedron *P*. You don't yet know if this
is counterclockwise from the outside, so that the right-hand-rule gives an
outward pointing normal from the cross product.

Now orient an adjacent face F1 to be compatible with F0's orientation, in that
the shared edge is oriented → in F0 and ← in F1. Continue propagating the
orientations of faces until every face of *P* is consistent with F0. So now all normals
either point inward or all point outward.

Now compute the volume of *P* by summing signed tetrahedra volumes. The volume
will be positive if all faces are oriented counterclockwise, and negative
if all clockwise. If it comes out negative, reverse all face orientations.

Computing the signed volume is all over the web, including here: 
[*Computational Geometry in C*](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/compgeom.html).